# Android, java: how to use public arrays in asynctasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, arrays

I have a string array in my class, I'm trying to use it in an asynctask, but before even being able to run, the line in the asynctask where i use the array has an error saying "cannot be resolved to a variable". i need to use the array outside of the asynctask so i can't just make the array inside the asynctask.

when i hover over the error it gives me two options, either "Create field 'myarray' in type 'myclass'" Or "Create constant 'myarray' in type 'myclass'". both will get rid of the error, but neither actually work, because when i run the program i get another error, both will say "null pointer exception", but the first option will give me the error at the point of using the erray in the async task, the second option will give me the error later in the process when another function in the class uses it (a non asynctask function). Even if i comment out the part in that function where it uses the array I still get a null pointer exception but it happens in during the asynctask, which i don't understand how that error doesn't come up before i commented out the function that uses the array because that happens after the async task.

I know that is a bit drawn out, i simply need to know how to create an array in the class and then use it inside an asynctask, i've tried setting my array as public, public static final, etc, nothing works. please help.

my code is incredibly long so i'll just show a few things below, the first line is how i defined/initiated my original String array in my class before the onCreate,the second and third lines are the automatically generated options that were given when i hovered over the error, they are in same order i explained them in. I of course keep 2 of the 3 commented out when I run it.

```
    public String[] divyeild = new String[1000];
    public String[] divyield;
    public static final String[] divyield = null;
```

And then the line below is where i use the array inside the asynctask, 'c' is from a loop.

```
    divyield[c]="anything";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] divyeild = new String[1000];

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Vois, Void, Void>{
        private String[] divyeild;

        public MyTask(String[] params){
             this.divyeild = params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             /* You can use this.divyeild here*/
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask(divyeild);
        ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] divyeild = new String[1000]; // Work fine
public String[] divyield; // Doesn't work if you don't assign value
public static final String[] divyield = null; // Can't work because you can not re-assign value for this array.
```

In the first way. All of the item are null. Because you doesn't assign yet. (String is a Object - it must be assign before use.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < divyeild.length; i++) {
    divyeild[i] = ""; // Assign empty string.
}
```

Of course, this is the best way. I don't suggest you use this.

```
if (divyeild != null) {
    // Please check null before use.
}
```